# Play locally stored HTML5 video on Android

Tags: android, html, video

I'm making a webpage that needs to run completely offline on Android 4.1 tablet. I'm trying to embed video stored locally on SD card using HTML5 `<video>` tag. Source attribute is pointing to a subdirectory containing that video using relative path.

The problem is, that after hitting play button, video stays black and plays only sound. After enabling video fullscreen, it plays normally. Same behavior in both native browser and Chrome. When I set source to same video stored online, or enable web server on the tablet and load the video from localhost, everything works fine and embedded video plays well.

Is there any way to force local video to play in embedded mode on Android? Or is this behavior for some security reasons?

Comment: is this being played back from  browser, or from a webview? if it's a webview you probably need to enable hardware acceleration and use WebChromeClinet - see https://gist.github.com/3718414 - to get it to play consistently.

Comment: if it's in a webview have you enabled hardware acceleration - see https://gist.github.com/Offbeatmammal/3718414 for an example

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue. Can you check if your video is within the specs listed here http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: You should add all three video formats to your HTML. There's .mp4, .webm and .ogg. Sometimes, the browser may fail to open .mp4 and can fall back on a format it can handle. Try including all three possible formats.

Comment: Still no answer to this? Looking for same